# y''+3y' = 144sin(3t) + 90 cos(3t) - need help on particular side

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm having trouble on this problem. I did it and received an incorrect answer, so I tried pluggin it into Wolframalpha.

Wolframalpha:

$y = c_1 e^{-3t} + c_2 + 72t^2-48t + 5sin(3t) - 5cos(3t)$

I successful got the homogenous part

$c_1 e^{-3t} + c_2$

When I did the particular side I received the sin and cos, but I'm not sure where the $72t^2 $and $-48t$ came from.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a final in 2 weeks and I'm trying to understand this.

Comment: Hi @Mhsmith21! $\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you plugged it in correctly?  Wolfram alpha [gave me this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+y%27%27%2B3y%27+%3D+144sin%283t%29+%2B+90+cos%283t%29): 
$$y=c_1e^{-3t}+c_2-3\sin(3t)-13\cos(3t)$$

Either way, if you proceed by the method of undetermined coefficients, the particular solution you seek will have the form 
$$y_p = A\sin(3t)+B\cos(3t)$$
Plugging this into the ODE (verification is left to you) leaves you with
$$(-9A-9B)\sin(3t) + (9A-9B)\cos(3t) = 144\sin(3t) + 90\cos(3t)$$
and hence
$$\left\{\begin{aligned} -9A-9B &= 144\\ 9A-9B &= 90 \end{aligned}\right.$$
Solving this system should give you the coefficients for the desired particular solution.